# React Js - Alterar quantidade apenas de um elemento no array

Tags: react

iPossuo um Array com varios produtos, porem preciso controlar a quantidade separada dos mesmos. Estou utilizando o useState porém ele altera a quantidade de todos os elementos.

```jsx
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { MinusCircleIcon } from '@heroicons/react/solid'
import { PlusCircleIcon } from '@heroicons/react/solid'


const RenderItemResumo = () => {

    const [quantidade, setQuantidade] = useState(1);

    const itens = [
        {
            id: "1",
            item: "Pizza Salgada",
            complemento: "1/2 Bacon",
            quantidade: "1",
            valor: "28,00",
            total: "28,00"
        },
        {
            id: "2",
            item: "Pizza Salgada",
            complemento: "1/2 Bacon",
            quantidade: "1",
            valor: "28,00",
            total: "28,00"
        },
        {
            id: "3",
            item: "Pizza Salgada",
            complemento: "1/2 Bacon",
            quantidade: "1",
            valor: "28,00",
            total: "28,00"
        }

    ]

 const final = itens.map(item =>
      <div className="flex-2  w-32 text-center">
           <div className="space-x-0 flex mb-2 mx-3">
                <label>
                   <div className="mt-7 ml-3">
                       <button onClick={() => setQuantidade(item.quantidade < 1 ? 0 : item.quantidade = (item.quantidade - 1))}>
                          <MinusCircleIcon className="h-6 w-6 text-red-600 ml-2" />
                       </button>
                    </div>
                 </label>
                 <label>
                   <div className="mt-7 ml-3">
                      {item.quantidade = quantidade}
                   </div>
                 </label>
                 <label>
                   <div className="mt-7 ml-2">
                       <button onClick={() => setQuantidade(item.quantidade = (item.quantidade + 1))}>
                          <PlusCircleIcon className="h-6 w-6 text-green-600 mr-2" />
                       </button>
                   </div>
                </label>
            </div>
      </div>
  );
```

Quando apertar no ícone plus ou minus, preciso que ele atualize somente a quantidade do elemento selecionado, como faço isso?

Answer (score 2):

você declarou apenas um estado e utilizou ele em todos os componentes. o resultado é justamente o que vc descreveu. o queria mais interessante, é criar um elemento separado para cada item, e lá usar o useState. assim, cada elemento terá seu estado separado

```
const Produto = ({ item }) => {
  const [quantidade, setQuantidade] = useState(parseInt(item.quantidade));
  return (
    <div>
      <p>
         <span>{item.item}</span>
      </p>
      <p>
        quantidade = <span>{quantidade}</span>
      </p>
      <button
        onClick={() => setQuantidade(quantidade < 1 ? 0 : quantidade - 1)}
      >
         Menos
      </button>
      <button onClick={() => setQuantidade(quantidade + 1)}> Mais</button>
    </div>
  );
};

const RenderItemResumo = () => {
  const itens = [
    {
      id: "1",
      item: "Pizza Salgada",
      complemento: "1/2 Bacon",
      quantidade: "1",
      valor: "28,00",
      total: "28,00",
    },
    {
      id: "2",
      item: "Pizza Salgada",
      complemento: "1/2 Bacon",
      quantidade: "1",
      valor: "28,00",
      total: "28,00",
    },
    {
      id: "3",
      item: "Pizza Salgada",
      complemento: "1/2 Bacon",
      quantidade: "1",
      valor: "28,00",
      total: "28,00",
    },
  ];
  return (
    <div>
       {itens.map((item, index) => (
        <Produto key={index} item={item} />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: Entendi meu erro, realizei o ajuste conforme você me passou criando um estado para cada componente e ficou ok. Muito obrigado !!!